# Syntax for conditional statements in Android XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

With databinding we now often see codes in layout files like this:

```
<Variable name="displayIt" type="Boolean"/>
```

and then later:

```
android:visibility="@{displayIt ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

(of course android.view.View must first be imported for View.VISIBLE and View.GONE to have any meaning)

This makes controlling the view much easier.
It also tells me that conditional statements are allowed in XML Layout, but it looks like my google-fu is weak, I tried and couldn't find the syntax for this.
What if I want to use literals? Something like:

```
android:text="{@isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"}"
```

(yes I know that's a stupid way of doing it, I am just talking about the syntax here).
Or what about resource ID's? Maybe like:

```
android:color="@{isValid ? R.color.green : R.color.red}"
```

Can it be done? What's the proper syntax?

Comment: edited to clarify. Strings such as `gone` or `visible` won't work though.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The correct syntax for calling a data-bind statement looks like `"@{<some expression>}"`, and so a ternary conditional would be

```
"@{bool ? ifTrue : ifFalse}"
```

Where those two values would be the (unquoted) values of what you would normally place into the XML without data binding.

For example

```
android:color="@{isValid ? @color/green : @color/red}"
```

Or, you can import a class that has a static field that you need, for example

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

And

```
android:visibility="@{isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

Both of which are shown in the [data binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: for visibility it will be `android:visibility="@{displayIt ? visible : gone}"` right 
??

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for you quick answer. I just tried it, `"@{isValid ? @color/green : @color/red}"` is the correct syntax; `"@{displayIt ? visible : gone}"` is not though.

Comment: Just wondering can we do day like if sunday then color is red

Comment: @stuckedoverflow If you expose `viewModel.isSunday`, then sure

Answer (score 25):

#### simple syntax

```
android:text="@{user.gender ?? `male`}"
```

is equivalent to

```
android:text="@{user.gender != null ? user.gender : `male`}"
```

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions), you have many available expressions

> ```
> Mathematical + - / * %
> String concatenation +
> Logical && ||
> Binary & | ^
> Unary + - ! ~
> Shift >> >>> <<
> Comparison == > < >= <=
> instanceof
> Grouping ()
> Literals - character, String, numeric, null
> Cast
> Method calls
> Field access
> Array access []
> Ternary operator ?:
> ```

Comment: Thanks, @khemraj. I was looking for the expressions that are available.

Answer (score 12):

You can also combine multiple conditions in this way

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@{sold_price == 0 ? (otherValue == 0 ? show_public_price : show_private_price) : (sold_price)}"
     android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
     android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
```

Answer (score 7):

If anyone wants to use the conditional statement as we do in "if" then below can be used in XML in any view.

app:visibleGone="@{model!=null && model.somevariable}"

replace above "&&" with "& amp;& amp"; (remove white space I intentially put here)

Answer (score 5):

For logical AND operation, use

> "&amp ;&amp ;"

rather than && with no space, I give here.

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.isCardSelected() &amp ;&amp ; !viewModel.isPaymentMethodEmpty() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```