# Databinding displays unpopulated value while waiting for the value to be populated in Android

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using databinding to display text on TextView using ternary syntax.

```
android:text="@{vm.value.firstValue != null ? vm.value.firstValue.toString() : @string/source1}"
```

This code displays `@string/source1` upon first loading of a fragment before the `vm.value` completely being loaded by network call. Then, it display `vm.value.firstValue` when the network call succeeds. However, I want to display the `@string/source1` only when network call fails.
I wonder if it is okay to display nothing(keep it empty) while waiting for the network call to be done successfully. then, populate TextView based on if a network call success or not. If this sounds okay, I would like to know how to acheive that using databinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The databinding framework cannot discern between a `null` value that is caused by the loading not being finished yet and a `null` value that is the result after loading. So you would have to implement such a discernment logic yourself.

You could introduce a new `isLoading` boolean in your ViewModel. Whenever you trigger a loading operation, set `isLoading=true`, and after the loading is finished, set `isLoading=false`. Then use the following condition in your XML:

```
android:text="@{vm.isLoading ? (@string/textIsLoading) : (vm.value.firstValue != null ? vm.value.firstValue.toString() : @string/source1)}"
```

You probably can further simplify the above statement like this:

```
android:text="@{vm.isLoading ? (@string/textIsLoading) : (vm.value.firstValue ?? @string/source1)}"
```

For an explanation of the `??` operator, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51763122/8331157).

---

If you don't want to create a new boolean variable in your ViewModel, you also can also initialize your `value.firstValue` variable to a default string that is displayed while loading:

```
value.firstValue = "Text is loading..."  // replace with R.string later
```

When loading the text fails, just set

```
value.firstValue = null
```

And then use the following statement in your XML:

```
android:text="@{vm.value.firstValue ?? @string/source1}"
```